# Adding multiple documents using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My user wants to add multiple students to the database by loading them from a .json file. When creating an individual user, I don't have any errors, but if I try to do more than one simultaneous insertion, many errors appear.

I tried using a for loop that does three things: - To prepare an object following the database model - What if there is a student with the same id already in the BD - Add it in case it doesn't exist

```
function addStudentsFromCSV(req, res) {
    var file_input_name = 'files/data.csv';
    var student_to_add = csv2json.getJsonFromCsv(file_input_name);
    var errors = new Array();

    for(var i=0; i<student_to_add.length; i++) {
    var student = new Student();
        var name;

    student.user_status = -1;
    student.study_program = 'CS';
    student.start_year = null;
    student.house = null;
    student.do_group = null;

    name = student_to_add.SortableName.split(",", 2);
    name[1] = name[1].replace(/^ /g, '');
    student.name = name[1];
    student.surname = name[0];

    student.email = student_to_add[i].Email;
    student.s_number = student_to_add[i].StudentNumber;

    Student.find({
        s_number: student.snumber
    }).exec((err, students) => {
        if(err) {
        errors.push("User " + student.snumber + " has an error");
        }
        if(students && students.length >= 1) {
        errors.push("User " + student.snumber + " already exists");
        } else { 
        errors.push("User added");
        student.save();
        }
    });
    }
    return res.status(500).send({
    errors: errors
    });         
};

module.exports = {
    csv,
    addStudentsFromCSV
}
```

This is my error message:
TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined at C:\creating_groups_app\backend\controllers\admin.js:92:15 at C:\creating_groups_app\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4739:16 at C:\creating_groups_app\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:263:16 at C:\creating_groups_app\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4225:11 at C:\creating_groups_app\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at C:\creating_groups_app\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4741:13
at C:\creating_groups_app\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:263:16 [... lines matching original stack trace ...] at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)

**Can somebody help me?**
Thanks in advance

Comment: for-loops can be hard to use with asynchronous calls. After the asynchronous call finishes, `i` will be `students_to_add.length` & that's likely where your error is coming from. It's worth either using async/await or something like bluebird to properly orchestrate your asychronous calls.

Comment: As far as ensuring that multiple students don't share the same id -- the easiest way of handling that is to create a unique index on your id field. It's simpler (and it doesn't have a race condition)